# Where is the gem ember-dev?

Tags: ruby, ember.js, rubygems, rackup

Digging around [emberjs git repo](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js), I found the file config.ru, which contains the line  **require 'ember-dev'**. I started `rackup` without any errors, but when I then tried `irb -rember-dev` , I got a load error.

Comment: is your `irb -rember-dev` just a typo in your post or have you really tried this with the _r_ in front?

Comment: `irb -r ember-dev` raise the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember-dev is a [repository hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/Gemfile#L4). Try to start irb in the bundler environment

```
bundle exec irb -r ember-dev
```

Comment: It's [bundler](http://gembundler.com/). It will limit the gems that are able to be run to what's listed in your Gemfile instead of one that is just on your system not designated by your project's Gemfile.

Comment: @spullen As you said, it limits. But usually does not add gems that cannot be required w/o bundler. The only reason why this could happen is, that bundler is configured to load gems from a custom path. @Vacker You can find out where the gem is from by running `bundle exec gem which ember-dev`.